# Pasta Salad+Chicken freezer storage for a week?

Tags: storage-lifetime

Maybe this is silly, but im a bit paranoid when it comes to spoilage and me and my wife are doing this new "make lunch for a week" thing to save money and stop us from eating out.

Anyways this week is home-made pasta salad with home-made italian dressing + Baked Chicken (Had a very easy marinade for a couple of hours as well)

Anyways, since Pasta Salad/Cooked Chicken typically lasts 3-5 days in the fridge apparently (and i'd rather err on the side of caution) I said we should just stick it in the freezer and then take out our little Tupperware (we just made individual portions for the week)

Anyways my wife thinks this won't work or will make it taste terrible, I figure a week shouldn't affect anything? Plus we get the added benefit of it not going bad?

Does this seem like a good plan? or just dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd seriously doubt it going bad in 5 days if your fridge is set to a proper temperature and it was prepared with some semblance of proper sanitation. A vat of the stuff taken out of the fridge for serving 4 times, yes. An individual serving stored in the fridge the whole time, I doubt.

The pasta texture will get weird from freezing/thawing. Should not actually affect the flavor if it's properly sealed. You may or may not find the texture change acceptable. Your wife may or may not agree with you.

As usual, experimentation will be your best guide as to whether **you** find it acceptable or not, so freeze one and don't freeze one and compare the two when you eat them.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who loves leftovers, I have eaten meals that have been in my refrigerator for up to a week with no issues.  The key here is to use a thermometer to make sure your refrigerator maintains a temp around 35 degrees.  This keeps food far enough from the danger zone of 40+ degrees and above freezing.

I also freeze a lot of leftovers for a couple months at a time.  Here the key is how you store.  I think that vacuum sealing is ideal but if properly wrapped and sealed you will be able to minimize the freezer ice that inevitably forms.  Freezing for a week should be no problem.  Also keep in mind that some things freeze better than others.  To be fair, I have never froze pasta salad but I have froze lasagna, ravioli and other pastas with no problems.  May I suggest you freeze a small portion as a tester so that, if your pasta salad/chicken meal is a regular, you will know for the future. And you can let us all know :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem freezing pasta, especially if it's only for a week. You want to minimise the amount of air around the pasta, so using a freezer bag and giving it a (gentle) squeeze is advisable.

Remember to defrost it safely - don't leave it on the counter overnight. The chicken shouldn't be at room temperature for more than a couple of hours, assuming it was properly refrigerated throughout it's pre-frozen time (the couple of hours is cumulative).

Comment: The air is just to prevent freezer burn right? Im using tupperware containers. For dethawing I just put it in the fridge the night before. Then reheat the chicken in the microwave. that should be safe right?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes! Make sure it is piping hot throughout when you reheat it.